# Show fixed progress below navigation bar between different view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uikit, mvp

I have a long register form that consists of 4 steps (the content is not relevant), here are the mockups:

[image: four screens with a common progress bar]

My problem is that I need to share a progress view between multiple views. This view should have an animation of growth. What would be the right and clean way to do this with UIKit? Should I create a custom Navigation Bar with that progress? Or use child controllers in some way?

I've been searching over here but the other questions I found are very old (like 7 years ago) and I don't know if there could be better solutions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want the "progress view" to remain visible and in-place as the next controller slides-in?

Comment: Create a new `UIWindow` instance and inject its view in `.rootViewController`

Comment: Exactly @DonMag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this...

One common approach is to set the "progress view" as the navigation bar's Title View -- but that won't show it *below* the navigation bar.

So, another approach is to subclass `UINavigationController` and add a "progress view" as a subview. Then, implement `willShow viewController` and/or `didShow viewController` to update the progress.

As a quick example, assuming we have 4 "steps" to navigate to...

We'll start with defining a "base" view controller, with two properties that our custom nav controller class will use:

```
class MyBaseVC: UIViewController {

    // this will be read by ProgressNavController
    //  to calculate the "progress percentage"
    public let numSteps: Int = 4
    
    // this will be set by each MyBaseVC subclass,
    //  and will be read by ProgressNavController
    public var myStepNumber: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // maybe some stuff common to the "step" controllers
    }
    
}
```

Then, each "step" controller will be a subclass of `MyBaseVC`, and will set its "step number" (along with anything else specific to that controller):

```
class Step1VC: MyBaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myStepNumber = 1
        
        // maybe some other stuff specific to this "step"
    }
    
}
class Step2VC: MyBaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myStepNumber = 2
        
        // maybe some other stuff specific to this "step"
    }
    
}
class Step3VC: MyBaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myStepNumber = 3
        
        // maybe some other stuff specific to this "step"
    }
    
}
class Step4VC: MyBaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myStepNumber = 4
        
        // maybe some other stuff specific to this "step"
    }
    
}
```

Then we can setup our custom nav controller class like this (it's not really as complicated as it may look):

```
class ProgressNavController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    private let outerView = UIView()
    private let innerView = UIView()
    private var pctConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        // for this example, we're using a simple
        //  green view inside a red view
        //  as our "progress view"
        
        // we set it up here, but we don't add it as a subview
        //  until we navigate to a MyBaseVC
        
        // we know we're setting
        //  outerView height to 20
        //  innerView height to 12 (4-points top/bottom "padding")
        // so let's round the ends of the innerView
        innerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        
        outerView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        innerView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        
        outerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        innerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        outerView.addSubview(innerView)
        
        // initialize pctConstraint
        pctConstraint = innerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: .leastNonzeroMagnitude)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            innerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerView.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            innerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            innerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            pctConstraint,
        ])

        self.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        
        // if the next VC to show
        //  is a MyBaseVC subclass
        if let _ = viewController as? MyBaseVC {
            
            // add the "progess view" if we're coming from a non-MyBaseVC controller
            if outerView.superview == nil {
                
                view.addSubview(outerView)
                
                let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    
                    outerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
                    outerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
                    outerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
                    outerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
                    
                ])
                
                // .alpha to Zero so we can "fade it in"
                outerView.alpha = 0.0
                
                // we just added the progress view,
                //  so we'll let didShow "fade it in"
                //  and update the progress width
                
            } else {
                
                self.updateProgress(viewController)

            }
            
        } else {
            
            if outerView.superview != nil {
                // we want to quickly "fade-out" and remove the "progress view"
                //  if the next VC to show
                //  is NOT a MyBaseVC subclass
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                    self.outerView.alpha = 0.0
                }, completion: { _ in
                    self.outerView.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.pctConstraint.isActive = false
                    self.pctConstraint = self.innerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.outerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: .leastNonzeroMagnitude)
                    self.pctConstraint.isActive = true
                })
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        
        // if the VC just shown
        //  is a MyBaseVC subclass
        //  AND
        //  outerView.alpha < 1.0 (meaning it was just added)
        if let _ = viewController as? MyBaseVC, outerView.alpha < 1.0 {
            self.updateProgress(viewController)
        }
        
        // otherwise, updateProgress() is called from willShow

    }
    
    private func updateProgress(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        
        if let vc = viewController as? MyBaseVC {
            
            // update the innerView width -- the "progress"
            let nSteps: CGFloat = CGFloat(vc.numSteps)
            let thisStep: CGFloat = CGFloat(vc.myStepNumber)
            var pct: CGFloat = .leastNonzeroMagnitude
            
            // sanity check
            //  avoid error/crash if either values are Zero
            if nSteps > 0.0, thisStep > 0.0 {
                pct = thisStep / nSteps
            }
            
            // don't exceed 100%
            pct = min(pct, 1.0)
            
            // we can't update the multiplier directly, so
            //  deactivate / update / activate
            self.pctConstraint.isActive = false
            self.pctConstraint = self.innerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.outerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: pct, constant: -8.0)
            self.pctConstraint.isActive = true
            
            // if .alpha is already 1.0, this is effectively ignored
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.outerView.alpha = 1.0
            })
            
            // animate the "bar width"
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.outerView.layoutIfNeeded()
            })

        }

    }
    
}
```

So, when we navigate to a new controller:

- we check to see if it is an instance of `MyBaseVC`
- if **Yes**

  - add the progress view (if it's not already there)
  - get the step number from the new controller
  - update the progress
- if **Not**

  - remove the progress view

I put up a complete example you can check out and inspect here: https://github.com/DonMag/ProgressNavController

Comment: Thanks for the response @DonMag, I'll give this a try in the short-term. Thanks a lot!